# Как установить pocketsphinx на python?

Tags: python, pip, распознавание-речи, pocketsphinx

Как установить pocketsphinx на python? Я делал все как описано [тут](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pocketsphinx), однако все равно выходит ошибка.

```
C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32>pip install --upgrade pocketsphinx
Collecting pocketsphinx
  Using cached pocketsphinx-0.1.3.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: pocketsphinx
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pocketsphinx ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\andrei\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ac2xos32\\pocketsphinx\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5dtckdk4pip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build_ext
  building 'sphinxbase._ad' extension
  swigging swig/sphinxbase/ad.i to swig/sphinxbase/ad_wrap.c
  swig.exe -python -modern -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/win32 -Ideps/sphinxbase/swig -outdir sphinxbase -o swig/sphinxbase/ad_wrap.c swig/sphinxbase/ad.i
  error: command 'swig.exe' failed: No such file or directory

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pocketsphinx
  Running setup.py clean for pocketsphinx
Failed to build pocketsphinx
Installing collected packages: pocketsphinx
  Running setup.py install for pocketsphinx ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\andrei\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ac2xos32\\pocketsphinx\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-a0wfgah_-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build_ext
    building 'sphinxbase._ad' extension
    swigging swig/sphinxbase/ad.i to swig/sphinxbase/ad_wrap.c
    swig.exe -python -modern -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/win32 -Ideps/sphinxbase/swig -outdir sphinxbase -o swig/sphinxbase/ad_wrap.c swig/sphinxbase/ad.i
    error: command 'swig.exe' failed: No such file or directory

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\andrei\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Andrei\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ac2xos32\\pocketsphinx\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-a0wfgah_-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ac2xos32\pocketsphinx\
```

Comment: стоит у вас swig?

Comment: @jfs , нет. Объясните, пожалуйста, куда и как его надо ставить. Насколько я понял, качать его надо [тут](http://www.swig.org/download.html), но что дальше?

Comment: "как установить swig нужной версии на Windows" это отдельный вопрос¶ Если у вас уже не настроен Си компилятор для расширений Питона,  то лучше уже собранные [двоичные] пакеты ставить, не пытаясь на вашей машине собирать. Поищите binary wheels для pocketsphinx (возможно неофициальные) или посмотрите доступен ли через conda пакет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне удалось установить `pocketsphinx` скачав установщик [от сюда](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pocketsphinx#downloads).

Answer (score 0):

Я скачивал по другому, и у меня получилось

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
pipwin install pocketsphinx
```